# Different behaviour of dataframe and series when editing whole row of Pandas Dataframe by boolean indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to change the whole row of a dataframe by indexing with a boolean array. I got unexpected behaviour:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]])
boolean_list = pd.DataFrame([False,True,False,True])
df[boolean_list] = 100
```

changes only the first column to:

```
     0  1
0    1  1
1  100  2
2    3  3
3  100  4
```

Why does this change when I use a pandas Series for the boolean indexing list?

```
boolean_list = pd.Series([False,True,False,True])
df[boolean_list] = 5
```

this changes the dataframe into:

```
     0    1
0    1    1
1  100  100
2    3    3
3  100  100
```

editing the whole row as intended.

Is there a mechanism that I don't understand and is this intended behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a DataFrame containing your boolean list (mask), that DataFrame has its own columns, e.g. `0`. When you write `df[boolean_list] = 5` where `boolean_list` is a dataframe, it applies the mask(s) in `boolean_list` column-by-column, so `boolean_list` has a column `0`, and the mask therein is applied to the `0` column of `df`. Since there is no `1` column in `boolean_mask`, the `1` column in the dataframe is left untouched.

On the other hand, when you use a Series as the mask, it's applied for all columns of the dataframe.

[tl;dr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71209344/different-behaviour-of-dataframe-and-series-when-editing-whole-row-of-pandas-dat/71209400?noredirect=1#comment125871324_71209400): Indexing with a dataframe matches on the index *and columns*, while indexing with a series matches on the index only.